# JRE included in JDK cannot be used as public JRE?

Tags: java

So I installed the latest Java SE Development Kit (jdk1.8.0_112) that come with JRE (jre1.8.0_112) so I notice I now have two JREs one I got from java.com (jre1.8.0_111)

So what I did is I uninstalled the (jre1.8.0_111) but then when I tried to visit java.com to verify if my JRE is working it seems like it does not work. it just ask me to download it which is the version (jre1.8.0_111).

My question is does the JRE included in the SDK is for development purposes only? and is different from the JRE the end users get??

Comment: Modern browsers like Chrome by default disables plugins like flash, java, silverlight, etc. You need to enabled it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

both JRE foot prints are same. only difference is additionally you get development libraries(+ JRE) with JDK(java development Kit) as opposed to standalone JRE installtion

Answer (score 0):

> My question is does the JRE included in the SDK is for development purposes only?

No.

> and is different from the JRE the end users get??

No.

What has actually happened here is that your web browser's Java plugin apparently cannot find the previously configured Java installation anymore.  The "verify" page is checking that the Java that your browser is using in its plugin is the right one.

- If you don't have Java enabled in your browser (**wise move!!**) then it doesn't matter that it won't work (!)
- If you do need the browser's Java plugin to work, the I suggest that you uninstall the JDK and reinstall it.  If that fails, you will need to dig deeper to find out why the plugin is not working.

Comment: lol I am using firefox to check the java version, but it seems like you and @Arvind were right.. I check the plugins on my firefox and it does not have the JRE so I manually added it via the plugin file included in the JRE folder and it's giving me an error "file is corrupted". I will do as you say and try to uninstall and reinstall SDK again! thanks!!

Comment: @CazyCoder Remember to [Accept an Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped solve your problem! :)

Comment: Actually it still didn't work, but I figured out why, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so reinstalling the SDK didn't actually solve my problem but I think I figured out what's wrong. So the JDK that I downloaded is for 64bit windows thus it includes 64bit JDK and JRE BUT the browser that I am using is 32bit! which is why it needs a 32bit JRE to run Java. So basically I need 32bit JRE for it to work on my browser.

(by default internet explorer and firefox uses 32bit regardless if u have 64bit OS, but u can freely switch to 64bit if you want but not recommended since some web content may not work properly in a 64-bit browser - got this info from [this link](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml))